# MAUI MVVM Navigation, how to navigate from page back to MainPage

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

I'm learning how Maui MVVM works.  I want to write code that:

- starts in `MainPage.xaml`, where there's a button that takes you to:
- `FirstPage.xaml`, where there's a button that takes you to:
- `SecondPage.xaml`, where there's a button that takes you back to:
- `MainPage.xaml`, where there's still a button that takes you to:
- `FirstPage.xaml` and so on

The problem is I can't go from `SecondPage.xaml` back to `MainPage.xaml`.

### Where's the problem?

The line of code I need to navigate from `SecondPage` back to `MainPage`, but it gives an error:

```
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
this line>> Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.MainPage), typeof(View.MainPage)); 
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.FirstPage), typeof(View.FirstPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.SecondPage), typeof(View.SecondPage));
        }
```

> The type or namespace `MainPage` does not exist in **ProjectName.View** (Are you missing an assembly reference?)

Alas, I am not missing an assembly reference.
It's worth noting that I moved `MainPage.xaml` into a *View* folder, but I still get the message when I move it back to root.

It makes sense that I wouldn't be able to put routing info for the starting page, as there sort-of already *is* routing code for it in `AppShell.xaml`:

```
    <ShellContent
        Title="Main Page"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
```

With all that said, how do I navigate back to `MainPage.xaml`?

### Here's my code for reference

Use the `CommunityToolkit.MVVM` Nuget package.
Add the dependency injections in `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPageViewModel>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<FirstPage>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<FirstPageViewModel>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<SecondPage>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<SecondPageViewModel>();
```

Add the routing information in `App.Shell.xaml.cs`:

```
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.FirstPage), typeof(View.FirstPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.SecondPage), typeof(View.SecondPage));
        }
```

For each page, do the following:
Create a ViewModel class for each Page.
Add Binding Context to the ViewModels from the Page's code behind:

```
public partial class FirstPage : ContentPage
{
    public FirstPage(FirstPageViewModel firstPageViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = firstPageViewModel;
    }
}
```

In `Page.xaml`, make sure that the file can both access and talk to its corresponding ViewModel, and add a button (or something) that has a command (*note this code is generic for every Page*):

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ProjectName.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:PageViewModel">

     <Button ... 
             Command="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Finally, make sure that there's a corresponding method for the Command in `PageViewModel.cs`, like so:

```
    public partial class PageViewModel 
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        async Task NavigateToPage()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(View.Page));
        }
    }
```

---

#### EDIT: in response to gratefully-accepted advice

(1) **Name your home page `HomePage`.  Don't confuse yourself.**
OK.

(2) ****In your MainPage.xaml.cs. The first line is something like** `namespace ProjectName.View;`  Take away the `View`.**
I don't have it like that.  Here's my file `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace EMS_MOBILE_MAUI
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage(MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = mainPageViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

(3) **Change the DI for `MainPage` from `AddSingleton` to `AddTransient`.**
OK.
Can you tell me if this next statement is correct?  It's my interpretation of the difference between `AddSingleton` and `AddTransient`:

> `AddSingleton` means exactly that: a static, one-time page.  On one hand, you can change the state of the Page, navigate away from it, come back, and it'll still be in that state.
> On the other hand, `AddTransient` will cause the Page to get re-"newed" if you navigate to another page and back again.

(3) You shouldn't have both of these lines of code:
*MauiProgram.cs*:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.MainPage), typeof(View.MainPage));
```

*AppShell.xaml.xs:*

```
    <ShellContent
        Title="LoginPage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
```

I don't have both of these lines.  I only have the second line.
Since the routing for `MainPage` is already in `AppShell.xaml.cs`, I don't use the other routing line.  I put that line in at the beginning of my question as demonstration of where I thought the problem might lie.

(4) **Read the docs.  Carefully.  For example, I bet you didn't know that you can navigate back with "..".**
Yeah, you're right. I'm not thinking about navigation in terms of a stack that you push/pop.  I will do that.

In conclusion, the only actual change I can make to my code is changing the `MainPage`'s DI from `AddSingleton` to `AddTransient`, which doesn't change the behavior in that I still can't navigate from any Page that I have back to the `MainPage`.  I bet if I read those docs instead of skimming I'll find my answer.

Comment: For the `AppShell.xaml`, is there only one  ShellContent <ShellContent
        Title="Main Page"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" /> in it as you posted?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT yes.  AppShell.xaml.xs has has exactly that `ShellContent/>` as you described.  It's the only element in the file.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you can see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

> The type or namespace MainPage does not exist in ProjectName.View (Are
> you missing an assembly reference?)

First, I advise you to name your page HomePage. MainPage is something very specific, I see that you are new, you will only confuse yourself.

Second, in your MainPage.xaml.cs. The first line is something like:

```
namespece ProjectName.View;
```

You do not have to move around the file. This line is what changes when you move it around, this is why you get it working sometimes, and sometimes not.

And if you have in this line `.View` you go with `View.MainPage`. And if you do not, you go with just `MainPage`.

Second:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
```

This should be changed to transient.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
```

Shell requirement. (Bad things happen otherwise).

Third:

Do not put routes like that:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.MainPage), typeof(View.MainPage));
```

At the same time with routes in the XAML:

```
Route="MainPage"
```

About navigation: Read this here, start to end: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation

Some clarification.

Let's say MainPage is my home, and I have SecondPage defined as global route, that I want to call from anywhere.

This means MainPage stays in the XAML.

```
<ShellContent
        Title="Main Page"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
```

And SecondPage stays in the CS:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(View.SecondPage), typeof(View.SecondPage));
```

When the app starts, it will look for the topmost ShellItem in the XAML (that is your main page), and navigate you there.

The navigation stack looks like this //MainPage.

Then you can call `GoToAsync("SecondPage")`. You will be navigated to SecondPage. The navigation stack looks like this `//MainPage/SecondPage`.

To go back you can navigate with ".." (the default behavior of the back button will do this).

Common mistake here is to call "//SecondPage". To be able to leave SecondPage as the only page of the stack, it has to be registered as ShellItem. (You need to add it the way you add your MainPage).

Start with two pages, do not try to write everything at once, because it will be nearly impossible to fix all mistakes at once. Build your project step by step.

Comment: Hi H.A.H.!  Thank you for the notes.  I edited my question in response.

Comment: @Bob if you do not understand specific part, I can add edits to explain it.

Comment: Hi H.A.H.  I'm sorry I didn't get back to you, and I appreciate your offer.  I read the Navigation page thoroughly, and I think I'm ok.

Answer (score 0):

1.According to your post details, you want to navigate back from `SecondPage.xaml` to `MainPage.xaml` like below:

```
SecondPage --> FirstPage --> MainPage
```

You should use [Backwards navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#backwards-navigation) which can be performed by specifying ".." as the argument to the `GoToAsync`.

So you need define your `SecondPageViewModel.cs` like below:

```
public partial class SecondPageViewModel 
{
     [RelayCommand]
      async Task NavigateTopage()
      {
          await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../../");
      }

}
```

2. Your project structure should like below, `MainPage.xaml`, `FirstPage.xaml` and `SecondPage.xaml` are included in View folder.

**View:**

- FirstPage.xaml
- MainPage.xaml
- SecondPage.xaml

You should define the `AppShell.cs` like below:

```
using EMS_MOBILE_MAUI.View; 

namespace EMS_MOBILE_MAUI;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
      public AppShell()
      {
          InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(FirstPage), typeof(FirstPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SecondPage), typeof(SecondPage));
    }
}
```

3. As to the error :[Compiler Error CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) below, there are many causes that can lead to this error. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246. And this error is irrelevant with DI: `AddSingleton` and `AddTransient`.